# Does Compose pool and reuse UI elements?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I've seen two different suggested methods of hiding widgets in Compose.

1. Set alpha to zero, analogous to Android's `View.INVISIBLE` because the widget still takes up space.

```
Text("I'm visible", Modifier.alpha(if (shouldShowIt) 1f else 0f))
```

2. Completely omit the element if it shouldn't be shown, analogous to Android's `View.GONE`.

```
if (shouldShowIt) {
    Text("I'm visible")
}
```

I would assume that in case 1, Compose will reuse the same widget element after a recomposition and merely draw it differently.

However, in case 2, does Compose have to allocate a new Text widget instance from scratch if the text was not shown during the previous recomposition but then becomes visible again in another recomposition? Or, does it use intelligent pooling of these widget classes?

From briefly browsing the source code, as far as I can tell, the nodes that we are building are automatically pooled. I'm specifically wondering about the UI elements that are generated from the nodes (the classes that are internal to the library but are responsible for the actual rendering). Or are these the same classes as the nodes themselves?

If pooling is not used, I would guess that the first method would be better for performance, even though the code is uglier.

Comment: I'm realizing there's no reason for there to be a separate widget class. Once you have a node and its associated layout state, rendering is nothing but a function with inputs. But then my question is more about whether a composable that was temporarily omitted from recomposition has to be measured and layed out again when it is added back into the tree, and if so, is setting alpha to 0 a better option for performance.

Comment: Hi, @Tenfour, have any progress about this?. I'll try to throw my 2 cents here though. So I'm not sure if this more of a memory performance hit, as we are dealing with function call stack, but I would suspect the performance hit here will be the `composition` stages, the second one might trigger the entire steps `compose` -> `layout` -> `draw` every boolean changes, the first one might be doing half of the `layout` stage then re `draw`. Just a wild guess based on my understanding with `composition`, thought I'm on the same boat, the first one seems a better approach for `visibility` use-cases